# Keep original column name order when using melt in R for variable number of columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

Feel pretty dumb not figuring this out on my own, but figure I'll just ask at this point

This is the data I'm using `www.google.org/flutrends/about/data/flu/us/data.txt` saved as a .csv in excel

At the moment I have 162 columns using the data and I want to melt the data so I can group values to region names to create boxplots for all areas side by side. Unfortunately, melt orders the variable names alphabetically and I want to maintain the original column name order. I'm unsure how to do this. I imagine it has something to do with factor levels from what I've been able to find on the topic so far. This is the code I'm currently using, data1 is the read.csv:

```
data1 <- read.csv('http://www.google.org/flutrends/about/data/flu/us/data.txt', skip = 10)
gr_data1 <- reshape2::melt(data1[-1]) #Group data for all US by area (variable) and flu trend (value)
```

I tried running this and then checking names(data1):

```
names(data1) <- factor(names(data1), levels = unique(names(data1)))
```

But as you can see below didn't really solve anything for me in the order.
This is what I'm running to make the plot:

```
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(na.omit(gr_data1), aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_boxplot() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Ideally Baton Rouge LA would be last and United States first

This is what the output looks like with the column ordered changed.
[image]

This is what the data looks like. There's 162 columns including Date.

[image]

This is what the code does to the data -> i.stack.imgur.com/CWMbu.png

Comment: set the levels of `variable` to `names(data1)[-1]`?

Comment: `gr_data1$variable <- factor(gr_data1$variable, levels = names(data1)[-1])` Gave the same output, sadly

Comment: I imported the original data and checked column names. The last column name is `Milwaukee, WI`, not `Baton Rouge LA`. Am I missing something?

Comment: *tilting head* when I check the table in data1 and scroll all the way over I see `Baton Rouge LA` but yes you're correct ...now that I check in the .csv it's `Milwaukee, WI` ..... Is the data frame in Rstudio just cutting off and not depicting everything? ..... I will feel so dumb if the data's in right order but just looks wrong cause R didn't want to show the full table

Comment: Gahhhhhh!!!!!!! Well, after the above occurred to me, I checked online and discovered the viewer has a column cap in view() at 100......so there was no problem. The interface just cant show everything :/ ........so many hours wasted :'(

Comment: I am glad that you found out what caused the issue.